# Connected to a proxy function but getting an error when I call the transfer function of the implementation contract

Tags: proxy-contracts, sepolia, stablecoins, usdc, etherjs

I'm currently working on a project where I can transfer USDC from my account to another directly, provided I have my provider and private key, programmatic. So I connected to a proxy contract on the sepollia ethereum network, that uses OpenZeppelin's Unstructured Storage proxy pattern for the implementation contract (Since the Ethereum Mainnet USDC Address uses the same pattern). I did the connection using the proxy contract address and proxy contract abi with ethersjs, but when I call the transfer function of the implementation contract from my proxy contract, (I read about how proxy contract transfers request to the implementation or logic contract then get the response and sends the result to the user since the user interacts with the proxy contract), I got an error saying "**transfer is not a function**" and when logging it using `console.log`, it's showing `transfer` function as `undefined`.

```js
class PaymentServiceUSDC {
    /**
     * Constructor for initializing environment-specific variables and creating provider and wallet.
     */

    CONFIRMATIONS = process.env.CONFIRMATIONS;

    constructor() {
        this.provider;
        this.signer;
        this.usdcProxyContract;
    }

    async init() {
        // Initialize the provider and wallet
        if (process.env.ENVIRONMENT === 'test') {
            this.provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(process.env.SEPOLIA_RPC_URL); // connect to blockchain
            this.signer = new ethers.Wallet((await wallet()).privateKey, this.provider); // create wallet
            // Initialize proxy connection
            this.usdcProxyContract = new ethers.Contract(USDC.usdcProxy.address, USDC.usdcImplementation.abi, this.signer);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Asynchronously transfers an amount to a recipient's Ethereum address.
     *
     * @param {Object} body - the input body containing amountInUsdc and recipientUSDCAddress
     * @return {Promise} a Promise that resolves to the status of the transaction
     */
    async transfer(body) {
        try {
            // Initialize the provider, wallet and usdcProxyContract.
            // await this.init();

            // Validate the input
            const data = this.validateInput(body);

            // Send the transaction and wait for the receipt
            const receipt = await this.sendAndWaitForReceipt(data);

            // Check the status of the transaction
            return this.checkTransactionStatus(receipt);

        } catch (error) {
            return ({ status: 'error', error });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Validates the input body, ensuring the amountInUsdc is a valid number and recipientUSDCAddress is a valid USDC address.
     *
     * @param {object} body - the input object containing amountInUsdc and recipientUSDCAddress
     * @return {object} the validated amountInUsdc and recipientUSDCAddress
     */
    validateInput(body) {
        const { amountInUsdc, recipientUSDCAddress } = body;

        if (isNaN(amountInUsdc) || amountInUsdc <= 0) {
            throw new Error('Invalid amountInUsdc');
        }

        if (!ethers.isAddress(recipientUSDCAddress)) {
            throw new Error('Invalid recipientUSDCAddress');
        }

        return { amountInUsdc, recipientUSDCAddress };
    }

    /**
     * Send a transaction and wait for its receipt.
     *
     * @param {Object} data - The data for the transaction
     * @return {Object} The receipt of the transaction
     */
    async sendAndWaitForReceipt(data) {
        // Send transaction
        try {
            const sent = await this.usdcProxyContract.transfer(
                data.recipientUSDCAddress,
                ethers.parseUnits(data.amountInUsdc.toString(), 6)
            );
            const receipt = await sent.wait(this.CONFIRMATIONS);
            return receipt;
        } catch (error) {
            if (error.reason === "InsufficientFunds") {
                console.error("Error: Insufficient USDC balance for transfer.");
                throw error;
            } else if (error.errorName === "ERC20TransactionReverted") {
                console.error("Error: USDC transfer reverted. Check contract state.");
                throw error;
            } else {
                console.error("Error transferring USDC: ", error);
                throw error;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check the status of a transaction receipt.
     *
     * @param {object} receipt - the transaction receipt to be checked
     * @return {object} the transaction receipt if status is 1, otherwise throw an error
     */
    checkTransactionStatus(receipt) {
        if (receipt.status === 1) {
            return receipt;
        } else {
            throw new Error('Transaction failed');
        }
    }
}
```

I'm currently trying to test the `sendAndWaitForReceipt` function which calls `this.usdcProxyContract.transfer`. But when it gets to that code I'm getting the following error:

```js
  1) PaymentServiceUSDC
       #sendAndWaitForReceipt
         should successfully send and return the receipt:
     TypeError: this.usdcProxyContract.transfer is not a function
      at PaymentServiceUSDC.sendAndWaitForReceipt (services\payment_service.js:466:55)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test\unit\payment.usdc.test.js:67:58)
```

which is making it difficult for me to stub the function for unit testing. Please I've not  really worked with Proxy Contracts and this is my first time. I believe the connection to the proxy contract was successful because I could call the read functions attached specifically to it.

The address to the Proxy Contract I'm working with is [0x1c7D4B196Cb0C7B01d743Fbc6116a902379C7238](https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x1c7D4B196Cb0C7B01d743Fbc6116a902379C7238). Can anyone please help me out with thi or tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `signer` is getting properly initialised, as you haven't defined the `wallet()` function in your class, from which you're accessing the private key:

```js
this.signer = new ethers.Wallet((await wallet()).privateKey, this.provider); // create wallet
```

Otherwise, you can directly create the `signer` by specifying your private key in your .env file, like this:

```js
this.signer = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY, this.provider); // create wallet
```

**Please ensure that you don’t have any mainnet funds in the wallet (or any account associated with the wallet) before using your private key as plain text in the .env file.**

Also, the `USDC` object against which you're using `USDC.usdcProxy.address` and `USDC.usdcImplementation.abi` should be defined anywhere outside the `PaymentServiceUSDC` class like this:

```js
const USDC = {
    usdcProxy: {
        address: '0x1c7D4B196Cb0C7B01d743Fbc6116a902379C7238', // USDC proxy contract address
    },
    usdcImplementation: {
        abi: [{ "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "internalType": "address", "name": "owner", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": true, "internalType": "address", "name": "spender", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "value", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "Approval", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "internalType": "address", "name": "authorizer", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": true, "internalType": "bytes32", "name": "nonce", "type": "bytes32" }], "name": "AuthorizationCanceled", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "internalType": "address", "name": "authorizer", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": true, "internalType": "bytes32", "name": "nonce", "type": "bytes32" }], "name": "AuthorizationUsed", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "internalType": "address", "name": "_account", "type": "address" }], "name": "Blacklisted", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "internalType": "address", "name": "newBlacklister", "type": "address" }], "name": "BlacklisterChanged", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "internalType": "address", "name": "burner", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amount", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "Burn", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "internalType": "address", "name": "newMasterMinter", "type": "address" }], "name": "MasterMinterChanged", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "internalType": "address", "name": "minter", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": true, "internalType": "address", "name": "to", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amount", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "Mint", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "internalType": "address", "name": "minter", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "minterAllowedAmount", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "MinterConfigured", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "internalType": "address", "name": "oldMinter", "type": "address" }], "name": "MinterRemoved", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": false, "internalType": "address", "name": "previousOwner", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "internalType": "address", "name": "newOwner", "type": "address" }], "name": "OwnershipTransferred", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [], "name": "Pause", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "internalType": "address", "name": "newAddress", "type": "address" }], "name": "PauserChanged", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "internalType": "address", "name": "newRescuer", "type": "address" }], "name": "RescuerChanged", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "internalType": "address", "name": "from", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": true, "internalType": "address", "name": "to", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "value", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "Transfer", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [{ "indexed": true, "internalType": "address", "name": "_account", "type": "address" }], "name": "UnBlacklisted", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [], "name": "Unpause", "type": "event" }, { "inputs": [], "name": "CANCEL_AUTHORIZATION_TYPEHASH", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "bytes32", "name": "", "type": "bytes32" }], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [], "name": "DOMAIN_SEPARATOR", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "bytes32", "name": "", "type": "bytes32" }], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [], "name": "PERMIT_TYPEHASH", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "bytes32", "name": "", "type": "bytes32" }], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [], "name": "RECEIVE_WITH_AUTHORIZATION_TYPEHASH", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "bytes32", "name": "", "type": "bytes32" }], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [], "name": "TRANSFER_WITH_AUTHORIZATION_TYPEHASH", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "bytes32", "name": "", "type": "bytes32" }], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "owner", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "spender", "type": "address" }], "name": "allowance", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "spender", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "value", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "approve", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "bool", "name": "", "type": "bool" }], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "authorizer", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "bytes32", "name": "nonce", "type": "bytes32" }], "name": "authorizationState", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "bool", "name": "", "type": "bool" }], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "account", "type": "address" }], "name": "balanceOf", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "_account", "type": "address" }], "name": "blacklist", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [], "name": "blacklister", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "", "type": "address" }], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "_amount", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "burn", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "authorizer", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "bytes32", "name": "nonce", "type": "bytes32" }, { "internalType": "uint8", "name": "v", "type": "uint8" }, { "internalType": "bytes32", "name": "r", "type": "bytes32" }, { "internalType": "bytes32", "name": "s", "type": "bytes32" }], "name": "cancelAuthorization", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "authorizer", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "bytes32", "name": "nonce", "type": "bytes32" }, { "internalType": "bytes", "name": "signature", "type": "bytes" }], "name": "cancelAuthorization", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "minter", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "minterAllowedAmount", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "configureMinter", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "bool", "name": "", "type": "bool" }], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [], "name": "currency", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "string", "name": "", "type": "string" }], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [], "name": "decimals", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "uint8", "name": "", "type": "uint8" }], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "spender", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "decrement", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "decreaseAllowance", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "bool", "name": "", "type": "bool" }], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "spender", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "increment", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "increaseAllowance", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "bool", "name": "", "type": "bool" }], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "string", "name": "tokenName", "type": "string" }, { "internalType": "string", "name": "tokenSymbol", "type": "string" }, { "internalType": "string", "name": "tokenCurrency", "type": "string" }, { "internalType": "uint8", "name": "tokenDecimals", "type": "uint8" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "newMasterMinter", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "newPauser", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "newBlacklister", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "newOwner", "type": "address" }], "name": "initialize", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "string", "name": "newName", "type": "string" }], "name": "initializeV2", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "lostAndFound", "type": "address" }], "name": "initializeV2_1", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address[]", "name": "accountsToBlacklist", "type": "address[]" }, { "internalType": "string", "name": "newSymbol", "type": "string" }], "name": "initializeV2_2", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "_account", "type": "address" }], "name": "isBlacklisted", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "bool", "name": "", "type": "bool" }], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "account", "type": "address" }], "name": "isMinter", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "bool", "name": "", "type": "bool" }], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [], "name": "masterMinter", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "", "type": "address" }], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "_to", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "_amount", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "mint", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "bool", "name": "", "type": "bool" }], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "minter", "type": "address" }], "name": "minterAllowance", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [], "name": "name", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "string", "name": "", "type": "string" }], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "owner", "type": "address" }], "name": "nonces", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [], "name": "owner", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "", "type": "address" }], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [], "name": "pause", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [], "name": "paused", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "bool", "name": "", "type": "bool" }], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [], "name": "pauser", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "", "type": "address" }], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "owner", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "spender", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "value", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "deadline", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "bytes", "name": "signature", "type": "bytes" }], "name": "permit", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "owner", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "spender", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "value", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "deadline", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint8", "name": "v", "type": "uint8" }, { "internalType": "bytes32", "name": "r", "type": "bytes32" }, { "internalType": "bytes32", "name": "s", "type": "bytes32" }], "name": "permit", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "from", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "to", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "value", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "validAfter", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "validBefore", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "bytes32", "name": "nonce", "type": "bytes32" }, { "internalType": "bytes", "name": "signature", "type": "bytes" }], "name": "receiveWithAuthorization", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "from", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "to", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "value", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "validAfter", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "validBefore", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "bytes32", "name": "nonce", "type": "bytes32" }, { "internalType": "uint8", "name": "v", "type": "uint8" }, { "internalType": "bytes32", "name": "r", "type": "bytes32" }, { "internalType": "bytes32", "name": "s", "type": "bytes32" }], "name": "receiveWithAuthorization", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "minter", "type": "address" }], "name": "removeMinter", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "bool", "name": "", "type": "bool" }], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "contract IERC20", "name": "tokenContract", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "to", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "amount", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "rescueERC20", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [], "name": "rescuer", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "", "type": "address" }], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [], "name": "symbol", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "string", "name": "", "type": "string" }], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [], "name": "totalSupply", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "uint256", "name": "", "type": "uint256" }], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "to", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "value", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "transfer", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "bool", "name": "", "type": "bool" }], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "from", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "to", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "value", "type": "uint256" }], "name": "transferFrom", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "bool", "name": "", "type": "bool" }], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "newOwner", "type": "address" }], "name": "transferOwnership", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "from", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "to", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "value", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "validAfter", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "validBefore", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "bytes32", "name": "nonce", "type": "bytes32" }, { "internalType": "bytes", "name": "signature", "type": "bytes" }], "name": "transferWithAuthorization", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "from", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "address", "name": "to", "type": "address" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "value", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "validAfter", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "validBefore", "type": "uint256" }, { "internalType": "bytes32", "name": "nonce", "type": "bytes32" }, { "internalType": "uint8", "name": "v", "type": "uint8" }, { "internalType": "bytes32", "name": "r", "type": "bytes32" }, { "internalType": "bytes32", "name": "s", "type": "bytes32" }], "name": "transferWithAuthorization", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "_account", "type": "address" }], "name": "unBlacklist", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [], "name": "unpause", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "_newBlacklister", "type": "address" }], "name": "updateBlacklister", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "_newMasterMinter", "type": "address" }], "name": "updateMasterMinter", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "_newPauser", "type": "address" }], "name": "updatePauser", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [{ "internalType": "address", "name": "newRescuer", "type": "address" }], "name": "updateRescuer", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [], "name": "version", "outputs": [{ "internalType": "string", "name": "", "type": "string" }], "stateMutability": "pure", "type": "function" }]
    }
};
```

Finally, you can call the `sendAndWaitForReceipt()` using the `paymentService` instance (i.e., an instance of the `PaymentServiceUSDC` class), after calling the `init()` function, like this:

```js
async function main() {
    // First, create an instance of the PaymentServiceUSDC class
    const paymentService = new PaymentServiceUSDC();

    // Call the init method to initialise the provider, wallet, and usdcProxyContract
    await paymentService.init();

    // Now you can call the sendAndWaitForReceipt function
    const receipt = await paymentService.sendAndWaitForReceipt({
        amountInUsdc: 100, // Example amount in USDC
        recipientUSDCAddress: 'RECIPIENT_ADDRESS' // Paste your recipient address that is expecting to receive USDC
    });
}

main()
```

**P.S.**, I've added the ABI in the value of `USDC.usdcImplementation.abi`.

You can even obtain the ABI of the implementation contract from the value of the `result` parameter in the response corresponding to this endpoint of Sepolia Etherscan:

https://api-sepolia.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address=0xDa317C1d3E835dD5F1BE459006471aCAA1289068

Comment: the wallet function is an imported function coming from a decryptKey file (a file that imports an encryptedKey.json file). I also have the contract address and abi in a constant  object imported as USDC. The connection to the wallet was valid, because I made successful calls to the proxy functions but I don't know why calls to the implementation functions were invalid.

Comment: @EyangDaniel, it seems to be working on my end. Let me add the **ABI** in my answer so that we can confirm you're using the same ABI as mine (i.e., of the implementation contract). The `this.usdcProxyContract.transfer is not a function` error implies that the ABI you're using does not have the `transfer` function.